# Is it possible to have one GTM container for Android, iOS and Web?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-tag-manager, google-tag-manager-server-side

I want to use the same Google Tag Manager container across all technologies, as the tags, triggers, and variables are pretty much the same.

Is it possible?

If not, is there an easy way of duplicating tags, triggers, and variables across containers?

The current *Content Types* that we are supporting now are iOS, Android, Web, and Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly it is not possible to use the same GTM container across your mentioned platforms.

To copy tags and variables, you can export the container in the Admin Panel and import it into other containers. However, tags created for a web environment will not work in a Firebase or iOS container, so there is no point in importing it.